# Is it a form of premature pessimization to check for equality prior to assignment when applied to primitive types?

Tags: c++, c

Having code that often modifies a non-local (member) variable (in a single threaded scenario, using primitive types), is it premature pessimization to just assign without checking whether necessary (considering that the modification of state has no other side effects as indicated in the code below)?

e.g:

```
static int someState = 0;
void foo(int newState)
{
  /* Which is better? This...*/
  someState = newState; /*Assign regardless*/

  /* ... or this... */
  if (someState != newState)
  {
    someState = newState; /*Only write when required*/ 
  }
}
```

I always feel the check is superfluous and would like to hear your opinions.

- Does the speed between reading and writing vary drastically to the point of considering the read check when the state change is made often?
- Is the extra check highly contextual?

I might profile this, yes, but I'm wondering about community consensus concerning something like this. I mostly just perform the assignment regardless, and I'm wondering whether this is how its done mostly.

Answer (score 2):

As usual, it all depends. First, you should try hard to have only one place in your code where the value is set (for example, a setter, or a property, depending on the language you are using).

If your application is using observers, or if some action needs to be taken if the value changes, then it is often better to check that the value is the same, and only take actions when the value changes. As a result, anyone calling the setter can do so in the knowledge that it is always cheap. That leads to the positive effect that there is only *one* place in your code where optimisation is needed.

Comment: If mentioned that in this case there is no side effects

Answer (score 2):

> using primitive types

and

> is it premature pessimization to just assign without checking whether necessary ?

Worse. It's adding an un-necessary read, compare and conditional jump to what should have just been a write.

> what about user-defined types?

Let number of assignments expected = N

Let number of times a redundant assignment is expected be U

Let Cost of equality comparison = C

Let Cost of assignment = A

So the ratio of redundant assignments is R = U / N

work we can save by checking = RNA

cost of doing so = NC

When invoking checking: Total cost of assignments = NC + (1-R)NA

when not bothering to check: cost of assignments = NA

so in order to determine whether it's worth checking for equality, we simply have to satisfy the inequality:

NA > NC + NA - RNA

NA - NC + NA > -RNA

-NC > -RNA

NC <= RNA

NC/NA <= R

C/A <= R

R > C / A

So if the ratio expected number of redundant assignments is greater that the ratio of the cost of a check (compared to the cost of an assignment) then it's worth optimising.

Can someone check my maths? It's been a while...

Comment: Good point. Expecting many redundant assignments may then make the check worth while. I can think of scenarios where one does expect assignments to be mostly redundant.

Answer (score 1):

In the case you mention, for a primitive type where no other effect will happen, I say assign always. It is not a premature pessimization. The value will be the same at the end either way and you'll save yourself the load and compare. I think adding the test for equality before the assignment is the premature pessimization.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things to consider:

- Are the types involved primitive?
- If not, how expensive are comparison and assignment for those types?
- If yes, is this variable `volatile`?

For primitive, non-volatile types the first option shall be faster. It is store vs. either load + comparison + branch or load + comparison + branch + store. For primitive types on modern processors, store takes almost the same time as load, so the first option is expected to be always faster.
It is especially so if the condition does not follow any regular pattern, and branch prediction would not work. In this case branch can take many cycles.

For volatile variable, the choice depends on what semantics you need (is it a control register of some hardware where writing to memory location causes some action, transfer via network etc?)

For classes, choice depends on the relative cost of comparison and assignment *and probability* of equality. In the first option, there is always an assignment. In the second option: if values are equal, there is only a comparison and branch; if not, comparison, branch, and assignment.

In general, it is:

```
Ta vs. (Tc + Tb) * p + (Tc + Tb + Ta) * (1 - p)
```

where Ta is assignment time, Tc - comparison, Tb - branch (may be neglectable if the class is complex), p is probability of equal values.

Also note, that some classes can contain this check in their assignment operator already.

Comment: I had primitive types in mind. I did not consider the fact that it may have been volatile. Good point